# How can {rational x where x > C} set be substantially different from {rational x where x < C} set?

Tags: computability, chaitin-constant

In the Wikipedia article about [Chaitin's_constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin%27s_constant) it is stated:

- The set of rational numbers q such that q < Ω is computably enumerable;
- The set of rational numbers q such that q > Ω is **not** computably enumerable.

As far as I understand, it also means that the set of q such as $-q < Ω$ is also not enumerable, which implies that negating a rational number changes its semantic somehow or that positive and negative "ends" of the number "pole" are substantially different.

Definition of computational enumerability seems not to depend on ordering of numbers inside a set...

Please explain this paradox. For example, why it's not the other way (<Ω not enumerable, >Ω enumerable)?

Comment: The fact that uncomputable numbers even exist is counterintuitive, and it's hard to construct one even though they are dense in the reals. Given that I don't think this is strange.

Comment: Why does it depend on sign "less than" or "more than" when definitions of other objects involved (probability, computability, etc.) seem symmetrical?

Comment: Everything depends on the definition of the constant. You shouldn't appeal to abstract notions of symmetry, especially not ones that are so sweeping.

Comment: $\Omega$ strongly depends on the meaning of numbers as magnitudes, so negative and positive numbers are vastly different. There is no reason at all to expect invariance under transformations that alter magnitude.

Comment: @IttayWeiss, Shall there exist a modified constant where q<Ω and q>Ω roles are reversed? if yes, how the definition would change compared to normal constant?

Comment: If you know the meaning of Chaitin's constant then you should see this makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the sentence that begins "As far as I understand it, it also means $\dots$"; it does not mean that.  The set of rational numbers $q$ such that $-q<\Omega$ **is** computably enumerable. Just run a sub routine that enumerates computably the $q$'s with $q<\Omega$ (according to the first bullet item in the question) and, whenever a number appears in that enumeration, reverse its sign and output the result.

Comment: Instead of $-q<Ω$ I probably meant $q<-Ω$... $(q>Ω)$ is like $(-q<-Ω)$ is like $(q<-Ω)$.

Comment: Just to cover the various obvious modifications, the following inequalities define computably enumerable sets of rational numbers $q$: $q<\Omega$, $-q<\Omega$, $q>-\Omega$, and $-q>-\Omega$.  In each case, the reverse inequality defines a set that is not computably enumerable. All of these facts follow trivially from the two that you quoted from Wikipedia in your question.

Comment: Is the difference in question like the difference between set of halting programs and set of non-halting programs?

Comment: @Vi0 The differences are alike in that a set is computably enumerable while its complement isn't.  They differ in that in the "$q$ and $\Omega$" situation, there's not only complementation but also arithmetic, which seems to have caused some confusion.